# balance has private access in SavingsAccount1, and won't let me access it in FlexibleSavingsAccount1

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, private

```
public abstract class SavingsAccount1
//public static double annualInterestRate;
private double balance;
private final int ACCOUNT_NUMBER;{

public SavingsAccount1(){
    this.balance = 0.0;
    this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER =0;
}
public SavingsAccount1(int ACCOUNT_NUMBER, double balance)
{
this.balance = balance;
this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
}
public abstract void addMonthlyInterest();

public double getBalance()
{   return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance){
this.balance = balance; 
}

public int getAccount_Number()
{
return ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
}

}

public class FlexibleSavingsAccount1 extends SavingsAccount1{

//private double addInterest;
public static double annualInterestRate;

public FlexibleSavingsAccount1 (int ACCOUNT_NUMBER, double balance){

    super(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, balance);

    //this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    //this.balance = balance;
    //this.addInterest = addInterest;

}//end of 

In this method I am trying to override, it says that balance has private Access in
```

SavingsAccount1, and won't let me access it's information.

```
@Override public void addMonthlyInterest(){

    balance =balance +(balance * annualInterestRate / 12);
}
```

}//end of FlexibleSavings Account

I've tried everything i can think of, so if the code looks bad i apologize ahead of time. I've been changing it up so much I don't even know what to do at this point. Any help you guys could offer would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Change this

```
private double balance;
```

to

```
protected double balance;
```

So that the sub-class can access it directly. Alternatively you can use `setBalance(double)` and `getBalance()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Methods and Variables that are declared private can only be accessed within the declared class itself.

Protected access modifier allows you to access the variables within the same class and all its sub-classes.